# Converting .mp3 to .aac

Tags: vlc, codec, audio-player

I've switched from Windows to Elementary OS, and the only part of my day-to-day life that is impacted by the switch is managing my music library. I like to have my library in .aac format, but I'm having trouble finding a way to convert my new music to .aac. I've tried the following applications

1. Clementine -- The conversion works, but the files come out as .mp4 "videos" rather than true .aac
2. VLC -- converting to .aac makes .ts files (it's possible I'm using this incorrectly - I don't understand encapsulation)
3. Rhythmbox -- this doesn't seem to do conversions
4. ffmpeg -- I tried a few times, but the output file is unusable
5. gnac -- couldn't get this to install (no Release file)
6. soundconverter -- this was the most promising originally, however the version in the repository didn't include .aac. I installed another version from a tarball which did include .aac, but the conversion hung before it even started.

Does anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

did you try [handbrake](https://flathub.org/apps/details/fr.handbrake.ghb)

or
winff

```
sudo apt install winff
```

Comment: YES, winff suits my needs perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: good to hear. I've found [ciano](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.github.robertsanseries.ciano) but you have to give it a permission for the home and devices from the application tab in the system settings.